# How to calculate conflicting meeting using data from Exchange server in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I am trying to get data insights of my calendar through visualizations in PowerBI. I am able to get almost all data from my outlook calendar using in-house API in PowerBI. I intend to find how many conflicting meetings I have per week, but I couldn't find any flag column for that. I'm trying to use time slicers to generate a what-if parameter to calculate a flag, but it doesn't work. Is there any way I can track conflicting meetings?

The data I have relative to meetings is as below -

[image: All the data i have pulled from the exchange server is here]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add a Calculated Column to the dataset, with a formula like this:

```
Conflicting = 
VAR StartDate = 'Calendar'[Start]
VAR EndDate = 'Calendar'[End]
VAR IDCurrent= 'Calendar'[Id]
RETURN
IF ( 
COUNTROWS( 
    FILTER (
        ALL('Calendar');
        'Calendar'[Start] < EndDate &&
        'Calendar'[End] > StartDate &&
        'Calendar'[Id] <> IDCurrent
    )
) > 0; TRUE(); FALSE())
```

This formula checkes if there are different rows within the same date range.

You can adjust the date comparions based on your needs. I've got the logic from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap) and removed the equal signs, to prevent contiguous items marked as overlapping.

The Id column is the Unique Identifier (like a unique, primairy key) automaticly provided by Exchange Online. The filter on Id <> IDCurrent makes sure you're not mark the current row as overlapping, e.g. it searches for all rows exept the current one.:

[image: ID Column Dataset]

Result:

[image: Outlook]
[image: PowerBI]

Edit: The formula above results in a true/false value. You can easily remove the if statement, to count the conflicting appointements, but remember that the value will be counted twice (or more); for each conflicting appointment.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I needed a flag value like your code provides me. I just have a small doubt. Does the "ID" in the code refer to the subject in the tr

Comment: No, the id was the Unique identifier I got back with the data from Exchange Online. Don’t you have it? Than maybe you should create your own key, with datetime + subject for example.

Comment: If you're referring to the last column of the data we get from exchange, then you're right. I already have it. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Yes, the Id column is indeed the latest column in the dataset. I'll add it to the answer. Gook luck!